# Postgres: Split column values & transpose

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a table like this:

```
category_id | product_id
---------------------------
1           | 1;2;3;4
2           | 7;8;9
3           | 6
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
category_id | product_id
---------------------------
1           | 1
1           | 2
1           | 3
1           | 4
2           | 7
2           | 8
2           | 9
3           | 6
```

I have tried splitting the column based on `;` but the product_id count varies based on the category_id. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: @Rezu It does not — OP wants to split into rows, not columns. It is also about [tag:sql-server], not about [tag:postgresql].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL's [array manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT category_id, unnest(string_to_array(product_id, ';')) FROM test;
```

`string_to_array` does exactly what it says — splits a string into an array of parts using a supplied delimiter, then `unnest` is used to separate an array value into multiple rows containing elements from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a function `regexp_split_to_table()` that does exactly what you want -- split a string into multiple rows  I prefer to be explicit about my lateral joins, so I would write this as:

```
select t.category_id, r.product_id
from t cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(t.product_id, ';') r(product_id);
```

However, if you prefer conciseness, you can write this as:

```
select t.category_id, regexp_split_to_table(t.product_id, ';') as product_id
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b981a345f652695d3d827fe3f938af22) is a db<>fiddle.